# Does Windows Update also update PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I'm aware that updating PowerShell for major versions (e.g., going from 4.x to 5.x) involves downloading an installer from Microsoft, but how are smaller updates installed? There doesn't seem to be a cmdlet to go from, say, 5.1.0x to 5.1.1x, so are these sort of updates simply handled by Windows Update?

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 is built-into Windows 10.  PowerShell 5.1 development has been migrated to PowerShell Core and working on the unified version (along with .NET Core).  It’s unclear what version of Windows you are using.

Comment: This is Windows 10. I have both 5.1 and 6 installed currently.

Comment: So I am confused by your question?  PowerShell 6.2 Core must be updated by hand.  PowerShell 5.1 will be updated through security updates and Windows Update.  As I indicated all PowerShell development has been migrated entirely to PowerShell Core.  So the only updates would be security until PS Core 7 is released.

Comment: on Win10 the updates to PoSh are automatic. there have been many `5.1.*` updates that are part of the automatic update system that win10 uses. this does NOT apply to win7, win8, or win8.1, tho.

Comment: That answers my question then. I'm talking exactly about the small updates, not major updates like 5.x to 6.x. If Windows Update handles those for automatically for Windows 10, then that answers my question.